# How to identify the exact issue which is reported in react-native crash logs?

Tags: react-native, crash-reports

If we encounter with any error while working, We get the exact line number along with `.js` file name. But this is completely different from crash report which comes from release apk. For example,

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: 
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateSh adowNodeProp (ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:113)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNode Setter.setProperty (ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps 
  (ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties 
(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView 
(UIImplementation.java:289)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView 
(UIManagerModule.java:364)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke 
(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke 
(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage 
(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run 
(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Is there anyway to identify in which `.js` file the current issue is located?